# Building a '2d' Haskell list

Tags: haskell

Let testFn be a function that takes two Ints.

I am trying to write a function that builds an N x M two-dimensional table (a list of lists) containing all the values of (testFn i j) for i < N and j < M.

How can this be done?

Comment: This can be extremely useful for `memoization` of function values, to implement dynamic programming for a function with 2 arguments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A list comprehension would be the easiest:

```
[[testFn i j | j <- [0..(m-1)]] | i <- [0..(n-1)]]
```

Comment: @chrislegend: note that leftaroundabout's answer isn't quite correct, as you can't use capital letters as variable names.

Comment: @ivanm: should this not have been a comment to _my_ answer? It's of course true, and I should have added a line to clarify that one needs to replace `M` and `N` by legal Haskell variable names, but so should have @hammar rather than just lowercasing them without explanation.

Comment: wonderful. Now, is there a nice way to "pretty print" say, `take` the first 10 rows and columns, so that each row falls on its own line.

Answer (score 2):

```
[ [testFn i j | j<-[0..(M-1)] ] | i<-[0..(N-1)] ]
```

where `M` and `N` are preprocessor macros to be replaced for the actual variable names (which must begin with a lowercase letter) in the process of making the code valid Haskell.